# How to show single data in popup window by clcking id using codeigniter with database

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

i want to show the single record by clicking button id using codeigniter with mysql. when i clicking the button ajax is not working.

views:

```
   <div class="demo1">
       <input type="hidden" id="porder" name="porder" value="<?php echo $result->po_id  ?>">
      <input id="btnSubmit1" type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Release"/>
    </div>
```

ajax code:

```
      $('.demo1').click(function(){

    var po_ids = $('#porder').val(); 
      alert(po_ids);

     $.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: "view_single_temp",
    cache: false,
    data: 'po_id='+po_ids,
    dataType: "html",

          success: function(htmldata) {
    }
    });
```

This is my controller code:

public function view_single_temp() {

```
 echo $po_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
  $details = $this->inventory_m->getpo_single($po_id);


print_r($details);
  if( $item_id = $this->inventory_m->getpo_single($po_id)){

  //print_r($item_id);
         foreach ($item_id as $item_ids) {
               echo $item_number = $item_ids->item_id;
              echo  $quantity = $item_ids->quantity_purchased;
             echo "<br>";
             echo  $name = $item_ids->item_name; 
             echo  $cost_price = $item_ids->item_cost_price; 
             echo  $sales = $item_ids->total; 
              echo "<br>";

            } 
        }
```

This is my Model code:

```
     function getpo_single($po_id) //purchase order list display function
      {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('bgs_po_list_items AS T1');
    $this->db->where('T1.po_id', $po_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

}
```

My pbm: 
my ajax is not working.
i want to get the data and bind in the ajax..

Answer (score 0):

Change Onclick on button. Make correction in url.

```
 $('#btnSubmit1').click(function(){

  var po_ids = $('#porder').val(); 
  alert(po_ids);

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'controllername/view_single_temp' ?>",
    cache: false,
    data: {po_id : po_ids},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(htmldata) {
    }
});
```

In Controller function:

```
 $this->input->get('po_id');   //to get the value of po_id.
```

Comment: In my code button click event is not working. when i clicking div id its is working but still ajax is not working

Comment: actually derive the data from db and single data is displayed on popup window by clicking row id. in my code button click event and ajax is not working

Comment: my pbm is using codeigniter to display the single record in the pop up window

Comment: Since you are using jquery. You need to load jquery library and place the jquery code in $(document).ready(function(){  //place your code here.  });

Comment: Ok is you code firing click event. Check using alert and also see console to see if any error.

Comment: How you are printing it in popup

Comment: get the single data using ajax and bind to the html table which is n popup @ hrishi